# Playv2.0.3: SecureSocial Module Routes are used (instead of main routes) after push to heroku

Tags: java, heroku, build, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I have a rather simple app that works fine locally, uses the correct routes, that is: /conf/routes for the majority of app routes, and /module/securesocial/conf for routes appropriate to that module.

But once I post to heroku, only the securesocial routes are used, so I receive an error message "Action not Found For request GET /" <-- or any route defined in the standard route file.

When I try to manipulate the routes (for example to create one comprehensive route file) I get a lot of different errors on compile...

Here is my standard route:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /foo                        controllers.Application.index()

GET     /admin                      controllers.Application.admin()

POST    /quote                      controllers.Application.addQuote()

GET     /quotes                     controllers.Application.getQuotes()

# Login page
GET     /login                      securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login
GET     /logout                     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.logout

# User Registration
GET     /signup                     securesocial.controllers.Registration.signUp
POST    /signup                     securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleSignUp

# Providers entry points
GET     /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.authenticate(provider)
POST    /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.authenticateByPost(provider)


# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

And here is my /securesocial/conf/route file:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
# GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

# Login page
GET     /login                      securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login
GET     /logout                     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.logout

# User Registration
GET     /signup                     securesocial.controllers.Registration.signUp
POST    /signup                     securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleSignUp

GET     /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.authenticate(provider)
POST    /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.authenticateByPost(provider)
```

I realize there is some duplication, but I this is the configuration I used to get the setup working locally (and it is similar to the sample as provided in the securesocial distro)...

If you can spot what I have done wrong, I would surely benefit from a course correction.

Thanks,
Chip

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple solution: merge routes from SecureSocial into your app's `conf/routes`.

Comment: I suggested: move NOT copy ;) just place the rulez from SS in main router config and... leave the SS' config blank

Answer (score 0):

I modified the way SecureSocial works to work around the bug in Play 2 that makes routes in submodules override the ones in the main app.

This new version does not require that you copy the module code into your app, but instead you get it as a downloadable dependency.

Try this:

1. Remove the module code from your directory structure.
2. Change your Build.scala file to include the following depeendency: "securesocial" % "securesocial_2.9.1" % "2.0.5".
3. Add a new resolver as part of the settings: resolvers += Resolver.url("SecureSocial Repository", url("http://securesocial.ws/repository/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns).

This is an example of how would look like:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    //
    // your other dependencies
    // 
    "securesocial" % "securesocial_2.9.1" % "2.0.5"
)
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  resolvers += Resolver.url("SecureSocial Repository", url("http://securesocial.ws/repository/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)
```

Hope it helps.